# 100% width & height for Wordpress Video (Horizontal scrolling)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, video

Salut everybody! I ran into a problem with a Wordpress theme I'm about to customize which is [Porta by wpshower](http://portra.wpshower.com)

I managed to find a solution in the past for vertical scrolling responsive widths but I'm unable to find one for horizontal scrolling.

I got the responsive height working for video iframes from Youtube, but it is no solution for me because the videos won't come from Youtube or Vimeo but will be stored in the Wordpress Media Gallery. (it doesn't fit the height of the container like the images and as I try to achieve it, but when I scale down the browser window it at least responds to it)

I got it to work by using

```
iframe {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

At the moment I work with the default Wordpress 4.1 Video player, the theme already has one line of Video CSS in it

```
audio,
canvas,
video {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

It works great when going to mobile & tablet, but I'm unable to achieve the fluid (100% width & height) for the Videos as it is done for the images.

Somebody has a solution/idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite understand the structure of the html code but have you set 100% height to all the containers that wraps your video div?

```
body,html,#allOtherDivIdsorSpans
{
   height:100%;
}
```

a demo of the page structure would be helpful.